# How to run Chainlink Project using eth-brownie python

Tags: blockchain, ether, infura, chainlink, brownie

I had installed eth-brownie using command

```
pip install eth-brownie
```

after  Brownie installed.I had bake existing Brownie project into a new directory.

```
mkdir MyChainlinkProject
cd MyChainlinkProject/
brownie bake chainlink-mix
cd chainlink-mix
```

then export infura.io project id and kovan network private key

```
export WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID='d1f95888fba84a42adasaa37803d4b5118ee'
export PRIVATE_KEY='0x5FE9bE1eC79dFE85b2748F6fEdasd60f811a8Ee997D9'
```

And at the end tried this command

```
brownie run scripts/price_feed_scripts/deploy_price_consumer_v3.py --network kovan
```

which returns with error

```
ChainlinkProject is the active project.
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 50, in main
    args["<filename>"], method_name=args["<function>"] or "main", _include_frame=True
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 53, in run
    module = _import_from_path(script)
  File "brownie/project/scripts.py", line 149, in _import_from_path
    _import_cache[import_str] = importlib.import_module(import_str)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Users.casper'
```

So anyone has idea about it. Thanks

Comment: Please don't expose your private key or infura ID online. If that is your wallet with real funds it it, please move everything out.

Comment: `cd chainlink-mix` how did this work? `Brownie bake chainlink-mix` generally returns a folder called `chainlink` not `chainlink-mix`

Comment: yeah its a folder chainlink and private_key and infura Id is wrong .I had changed it.Thanks

Comment: I’m going to bounty this if in a few days no one responds

Comment: Thank you for your support. #happyCoding

Comment: @PatrickCollins:  getting similar issue with MacOs and python3.9. Please help

Answer (score 1):

run your project outside of home directory. in my case my home directory C:/Users/nyamgavaa.g path inporter require there is no home directory with ".".
this way fix my issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this same problem in Brownie when I try to run a deploy script.

````
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.14.5 - Python development framework for Ethereum

ChainlinkProject is the active project.
  File "c:\users\brian, line line, in in
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "c:\users\brian, line line, in in
    module = _import_from_path(script)
  File "c:\users\brian, line line, in in
    _import_cache[import_str] = importlib.import_module(import_str)
  File "c:\users\brian, line line, in in
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)    
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Users.Brian Lee.```
````

Comment: we need to update smart contracts path into some config ?